# Which country has the highest number of Bricks and Mortal merchants who accept Bitcoin per Capita?

Tags: adoption

I have seen many online directories of Bitcoin merchants but fewer bricks and mortar directories.

Is https://coinmap.org comprehensive? The great majority all of the listings are for North America and Europe?  I hope that listings are being missed in countless other parts of the world.

Many say the 3rd world is potentially the largest beneficiary of blockchain technology but the current statistics are not painting a bright picture for adoption in most areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coinmap is definitely not comprehensive. I imagine most of the listings are in NA and Europe because the site itself is in English. I doubt there will ever be a comprehensive centralized repository of brick-and-mortar stores taking bitcoin just due to the nature of the network itself.